# How Can I write This in TeX?

Tags: formatting

[image]

I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to write the big bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `\left` and `\right` is used to achieve the big brackets.

You could achieve the equation by using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{ll}
F = B_{\perp}.I.l \\
\\
\sin{\alpha} = \frac{B_{\perp}}{B} \rightarrow B_{\perp} = B.\sin{\alpha}
\end{array}
\right\}
F = B.I.l.\sin{\alpha}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The output would look like:
[image]

Comment: Please write `\sin`, not just `sin`. Also, do please remove or comment out the `\label` directive as the displayed equation doesn't have a number.

Comment: Thank you @Mico I have edited the answer.

Comment: You may want to add flushright alignement before the closing brace thus it will better stick to @John Doe 's expectation.